# Android Library Declare-Styleable Runtime Error

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, android-build, aar

I have a library with some widgets in maven central. When I add that library as a dependency (from maven central) to a project using gradle, I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.my.pacakge.R$styleable
```

If I manually download the .aar and include that in the project, everything works fine. I tried using Android Studio's code completion to see if the library's `R` was included. When I use the maven dependency, typing `com.my.pacakge.R` returns no results, but when I use a local .aar it returns the `R` for the library.

Here's the library code:

```
// widget constructor
public ForegroundImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ForegroundImageView);
    Drawable foreground = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.ForegroundImageView_android_foreground);
    if (foreground != null) {
        setForeground(foreground);
    }
    a.recycle();
}

// attrs.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="ForegroundImageView">
        <attr name="android:foreground"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: Please show us the build files where you're including the dependency.

Comment: I have the same problem with my aar. I can't put my library on maven because it can't use styleable attributes.
"publishNonDefault false" not worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the dependency was getting published with [`publishNonDefault true`](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication).